# Get previous value on input event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a value that I must change dynamically : the original value is 6 and I can customize it. If I put 7 on an inputbox, I now have 13. When I add another number, for example 71 my value change by 13 + 71. I want to substract the 13 with the previous value (7) to get my original one which is 6.

Here is my snippet :

```js
$('.test :input').on('input', function(){

var ok = $('.ok');
ok.text(parseFloat(ok.text()) + parseFloat($(this).val()))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ok" style="background-color: white">
6
</div>
<div class="test">
<input type="text"/>
</div>
```

If you try to type 45 you should have 51 and you have 55.

I already tried with "focusing" as shown on some threads but I'm not leaving the input so it doesn't work. I don't know how to get my previous value.

Comment: Store it as a data-* value on the element?

Comment: I must do that into my "on" event because a lot of other features are modifying this number. Every time I'll go for this event it'll change the value...

Comment: An `input` event happens on every keypress, i.e. one with value `5` and the other with `51`. You need a button where you explicitly trigger the calculation with the current value (or some other, more complex way of distinguishing when one user input is "finished" and the next one starts).

Comment: @Bergi I think the OP *wants* the value to change on every keypress ("I put 7...when I add another..71"). They just want the original value (6) to be remembered even though they already added.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking for. But I can see your selector is wrong. Also you want to make sure the document is loaded before you query elements in it.

I change the event listener to an onChange so that the addition doesn't happen for every keypress.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.test input').on('change', function() {
    var ok = $('.ok');
    ok.text(parseFloat(ok.text()) + parseFloat($(this).val()))
  })
});
```

Here's a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/y0JYhx6IroFK6mWSWo59?p=preview&plnkr=next&utm_source=legacy&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=next) of it running.
Here's another guess at what you're asking, [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/y0JYhx6IroFK6mWSWo59?p=preview&plnkr=next&utm_source=legacy&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=next). Which stores the initial value as an attribute.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ok = $('.ok');

  $('.ok').text(ok.attr('data-initial-value'));
  $('.test input').on('change', function() {
    ok.text(parseFloat(ok.attr('data-initial-value')) + parseFloat($(this).val()))
  })
});

<div class="ok" data-initial-value="6" style="background-color: white">
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. This is close from what I'm looking for! But if I leave the input and come back to add a number it will still give a false result...

Comment: What do you mean by false result? Are you saying that after the input loses focus you want the number to return to 6?

Comment: Or do you always want one of the numbers to be 6?

Comment: Your second one is close from what I'm looking for. I already tried this but the problem is that the value is changed by other features.

Comment: Can you give a better explanation?

Comment: There is [an `:input` selector in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

As @Doug suggested, you might use an attribute to store the initial value:

```js
$('input').on('input', function() {
  var ok = $('.ok');
  ok.text(+(ok.attr('i')) + +($(this).val() || 0))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ok" i="6">6</div>
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for except that my value is not always the same, other features can change it...

Comment: @ZeyukanIch', "other features" can update the attribute as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for helping and hints, and sorry for messy explanations...

Here is what I did and it works : when I focus I put the old value in an attribute then when I add numbers I substract my actuel number with the stored number.

```js
$('.test input').on('focus', function(){

$(this).attr('value', $(this).val());

});


$('.test input').on('change', function(){
    var valActuelle = 0;
    if($(this).attr('value') !== ''){
        valActuelle = $(this).attr('value');
    }

var ok = $('.ok');
ok.text(( parseFloat(ok.text())  - parseFloat(valActuelle)) + parseFloat($(this).val()) );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ok" style="background-color: white">
6
</div>
<div class="test">
<input type="text"/>
</div>
```

It works only if you lose the focus but in my case I'm ALWAYS losing the focus